# Using wildcards to select all objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm using Angular to select several objects and all of them using 3 keys, starting and ending with the same keys, also their value is same, only the in-between key is different.

```
$scope.foo.one.bang = true;
$scope.foo.two.bang = true;
$scope.foo.three.bang = true;
$scope.foo.four.bang = true;
$scope.foo.five.bang = true;
```

Is there a built-in shortcut to use wildcards in the second key to select all relevant objects such as the below example?:

```
$scope.foo.[any].bang = true;
```

Comment: Well, you can use `angular.forEach` loop.

Comment: I don't know Angular, but in plain JS perhaps something like: `Object.keys($scope.foo).forEach(k=>$scope.foo[k].bang=true);` (use of arrow function is obviously optional).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, first we are setting all as "true" and then using angular.forEach setting all to false.

```
 $scope.foo ={}
    $scope.foo.one={}
    $scope.foo.two={}
    $scope.foo.three={}
    $scope.foo.four={}
    $scope.foo.five={}
    $scope.foo.one.bang = true;
    $scope.foo.two.bang = true;
    $scope.foo.three.bang = true;
    $scope.foo.four.bang = true;
    $scope.foo.five.bang = true;

    angular.forEach($scope.foo, function(value, key) {
        value.bang=false
      console.log(value.bang);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method in Angular.js to do it. You can use `Angular.forEach` loop, but it is pretty same as pure Javascript. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use simple iteration loop.

```
var obj = $scope.foo;
var objs = [];

for(let i in obj) if(obj[i].bang === true) objs.push(bang[i]);

console.log(objs); // All objects with that property
```